# how to place an image at the center of the browser irrespective of the resolution?

Tags: html, css

i want an image to be placed at the center horizontally irrespective of the dimensions of the image or the resolution of the browser. How can i do that using html and css?

its for the logo of the website and i want that it always shows up in the center of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #apDiv1 {
        margin:0px auto;
        top:0px;
        width:800px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="apDiv1"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2b/Small-logo.jpg" alt=""/></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: using this the rest of the website shifts down which i dont want to . There is adequate space in between. So what i did was added to your code position:absolute and width:100% and that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
```

You can also see http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center for more centering tricks.